# "Is for every proverb there an opposite one?" Does that question sound natural?

Tags: questions, proverbs

I want to make a question from the proverb "For every proverb there is an opposite one". Here are some attempts and why they don't work:

- "Is for every proverb there an opposite one?": the part "there an opposite one" feel unnatural to me
- "Is there an opposite one for every proverb?": "one" comes before what it points to
- "Is there an opposite proverb for every one?": the part "every one" can be mistaken with "everyone"
- "Is there an opposite proverb for every proverb?": repetition

One can go around this and ask "Is it true that for every proverb there is an opposite one?", but then how do we ask the why question? **"Why is for every proverb there an opposite one?"**

<sub>Just for fun question: is there any proverb for unnatural yet grammatical sentences?</sub>

Comment: _Is there_ is an idiom that it pretty well unsplittable. I find _Is there for each proverb an opposite one?_ to be better, though still awkward. A more natural way is to say _Does each proverb have an opposite one?_ (though I would probably say _Has each proverb got an opposite one?_, but not everybody likes that phraseology).

Comment: "Has each proverb got an opposite one?"? This seems to have a different meaning.

Comment: I don't know if you really mean "opposite" - perhaps you mean "a proverb that [contradict](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/contradict)s it". To contradict is *To assert the opposite of a statement or idea put forward by (someone).* Here are some examples: [15 Pairs of Contradictory Proverbs](https://www.derekchristensen.com/15-pairs-of-contradictory-proverbs/)

Comment: @ColleenV "To contradict is to assert the *opposite*". So why do you find "contradict" understandable, but not with "opposite"?

Comment: Because things can be "opposite" in many ways. Contradict (in this sense) is specifically for assertions, which is essentially what a proverb is - an assertion about what should or shouldn't be done, or an assertion about what is true. If I were going to use "opposite", I wouldn't say "that proverb is the opposite of this one", I would say "What that proverb says is the opposite of what this one says".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best and most natural way of expressing these, to me, is:

- "For every proverb, is there an opposite one?"
- "Why, for every proverb, is there an opposite one?"

or:

- "Why is there, for every proverb, an opposite one?"

or:

- "For every proverb, why is there an opposite one?"

in approximate order of how well I like them.

Comment: Nothing in the OP's text mentions anything about ***why*** people often say that every proverb can be contrasted with another proverb saying the complete opposite.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Sorry, but was that not literally the last line of OP's post (apart from the last "fun question")? What have I misunderstood here?

Comment: My apologies. I don't know how I managed to miss that! In my defence, that's not what the *title* says the question is about. But I'll leave my previous comment there as a testament to my carelessness (and that of whoever *upvoted* the comment! :)

Comment: It still sounds strange. I'd go for "Does every proverb have an opposite?" and thus "Why does ...". That's more what a native speaker would actually say.

Answer (score 1):

The cited example is *extremely* "non-idiomatic", but I don't think that's because it's actually "ungrammatical".

I was originally going to say it's invalid to introduce additional text between the first two words in interrogative ***Is there** something?* or ***Are there** some other things?* But then I thought about this example...

> ***Was ever there** a man so romantic?*
> ...where only a dyed-in-the-wool pedant would say that *must* be expressed as...
> ***Was there ever** a man so romantic?*

I can't see any reason why OP's (adjectival? adverbial?) ***for every*** is any different to ***ever*** in my example. So I have to say they're both ***syntactically valid*** - but whereas my own example is *just* the right side of "idiomatically acceptable", I'm afraid OP's example *isn't.*

---

TL;DR: OP's example is at the very least "clumsy", and should be rephrased to, for example,...

> *Is there an opposite one for every proverb?*

...where I would prefer to include ***one***, but that's an optional stylistic choice.